# Is it possible to change from a member of the Dawnguard, to a Vampire Lord or vice versa (permanently)?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I activated the Dawnguard DLC approximately three days after it's release/inception, in late June, and commenced actively playing yesterday: July fifteenth, though I had already spoke with Isran, leader of the Dawnguard, I completed what I recollect to be the first quest of Dawnguard yesterday, I recollect the sole objective simply as: 'find out what the Vampires are seeking', I proceeded to do so, rescuing Serana & returning her safely to Lord Harkon, her Father. Once acquainted with the Vampires, I decided to become one myself, accepting Lord Harkon's offer.

*Note: the above information is merely a scene setter, an introduction, and is ultimately unnecessary*

I am currently located in what I recollect to oblivion, in which I have located Serana's mother. 
I have, after much deliberation come to the conclusion that I am dissatisfied with Vampirism, and though I avidly enjoy being able to reek the plentiful benefits, I now sought to align myself with the Dawnguard, and wonder whether it is possible. Perhaps there is some path to restarting the quest itself as commencing a new game entirely seems somewhat far-fetched, and perhaps unnecessary even given my dissatisfaction.

I have however, heard of a cure, and ponder as to whether it is possible to attempt assassination on either Lord Harkon, or a fellow Lord Vampire. While I realise this shall most likely not result in their actual death, I inquire as to whether it shall have the same effect as the attack on a member of the Dark Brotherhood, and immediately initiate the quest against the band.

Comment: There is some possibility to join the vampire faction later: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bloodline#Notes but I think you do not become part of the vampire clan then. (You just get to be a vampire lord). But I'm not entirely sure, and have not gotten to this part yet). The link should help any wiki divers to get to the answer eventually.

Comment: It's called the Soul Cairn - for next time

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about any cures, but disabling/deleting the DLC, loading the game, saving the game, enabling/redownloading the DLC will reset your DLC progress.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any idea how to do so on XBOX 360, and shall it rid of the levelling I have done throughout the DLC.etc, or simply reset the storyline, as I already have many saves labelled Skyrim not Dawnguard with the DLC installed.

Comment: Apologies if that was slightly difficult to understand, I essentially just pointed out that the DLC was an in-game DLC, part of the current Skyrim game, not a separate map entirely or anything of the sort, and wondered whether this shall effect anything.

Comment: It won't affect your level or anything, but DLC-specific items will be removed (a dwarven crossbow will, a glass greatsword you found while playing the DLC will not), and DLC-specific quests will be reset.

Comment: Thank you kindly, I shall most likely do as you suggest anyway, yet I have created a simplified version of my original question.

Comment: I hope you do not mind, could I also ask where abouts I could retrieve the Dwarven Crossbow, and if you have any idea about how to retrieve Crossbow bolts as a Vampire, for I realise the Dawnguard hold many.

Comment: I don't know where to get it, no.

Comment: @user29304 You should create a separate question about how to get the Dwarven Crossbow and more bolts.

Comment: Thank you, I most likely shall be creating a number of new questions in the near future as there are some difficulties that have arisen, however could you, or perhaps kotekzot please tell me how to disable then reload the DLC? Such information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **This should not be done lightly**. Uninstalling DLC or DLC-like mods (even to reinstall) can have long-lasting effects on your save game and cause a number of issues in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news but once you start one quest line there's no going back.