# Is it possible to change sides on the Dawnguard DLC for Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to change from a member of the Dawnguard, to a Vampire Lord or vice versa (permanently)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76941/is-it-possible-to-change-from-a-member-of-the-dawnguard-to-a-vampire-lord-or-vi)

This is simply a simplified version of my extensive previous question.

Of course, there are two main sides in Skyrim's Dawnguard DLC, one can be either a Vampire Lord or hunter, of vampire, saviour of light: a member of the Dawnguard.

I simply ask if it is possible to switch from a Vampire to a member of the Dawnguard once you have initiated the quest as a Vampire. I am currently searching for the second Elder Scroll (as a Vampire), for I have found the one from Oblivion.

*Please reference my previous question: [Is it possible to change from a member of the Dawnguard, to a Vampire Lord or vice versa (permanently)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76941/is-it-possible-to-change-from-a-member-of-the-dawnguard-to-a-vampire-lord-or-vi) for a further background*

I of course realise loading games shall most likely lead to me to the option again yet that would be a last resort, perhaps even not an option.

Comment: Generally a "simplified" version of a more extensive question will be closed as a duplicate of the more extensive question. Could you comment on why you reposted a simplified version? It might help us understand how best to handle this question. If you just wanted to simplify your previous question because you think it was too confusing for people, you could merely edit the old one instead. This one, in its current form, will likely end up closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site! Thanks for your contributions, they've been really entertaining to read through so far. Instead of posting a new question though for the more general/simplified version of your post, please use the edit button to change your first question into this new, more general one. This helps to avoid clutter on the site, since as things stand right now we'll have two questions that tread over the exact same material.

Comment: Thanks to Mana for having the decency to... well, phrase yourself much more welcomingly, and openly. I shall note this for future reference. This isn't necessarily a duplicate, and it all honesty, I was using specifics as requested, like I said thank you Mana for your conduct, as for Sterno, thank you as well, yet (despite the revealing title) I would prefer if my work were to simply be left untouched, until you have confirmed with me that my work was intended as a duplicate. Furthermore, while I realise I am new I am slightly concerned as to how one can simply change the title of my work.....

Comment: .....Without my permission, perhaps this is the way the site works, if so I would have liked to/would like to receive elucidation to & confirmation of such. Thank you

Comment: @user29304 [This part of the FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#editing) discusses that other people can edit your posts. Basically, this entire site is a big collaborative effort, and people will sometimes edit in an attempt to make a question clearer or to work better with search engine optimization. If you disagree with an edit, you can click the "edit" button and revert to your previous version. As far as duplication goes, it's a site policy to close duplicate questions, since we want all the answers to be in one place.

Comment: You may be entirely correct that this is not a duplicate, which is why I was asking for clarification. At the moment, I'm having a hard time understanding what answer you're looking for in this question that wouldn't have fit the other one, and the end goal here is to get you the answers you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time for reply, I apologise yet I just struggled to distinguish the question itself (asking whether this was a duplicate). I suppose you could consider it a duplicate yet in all honesty I clearly stated it was a simplified version and thought that gave enough distinction in itself.